# Best way for User Login in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, authentication, nsuserdefaults

I want to make an App where the User has to log in. I wanted to ask if it is better and safer to work with NSUserDefaults or CoreData? Or are there any safer and better ways to do this?

**EDIT:**

how do i actually check if the password is the right one for the specific user? What i have right now is this :

```
 @IBAction func loginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(txtUsername.text == "" || txtPassword.text == "" || txtUsername.text!.characters.count < 5 || txtPassword.text!.characters.count < 6){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Failure", message: "Too short password or username", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else if(txtUsername.text!.characters.count > 5 && txtPassword.text!.characters.count > 6) {
      //Here i want to check if the password for the specific user is the right one
       }

}

@IBAction func registrationPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    username = txtUsername.text!
    password = txtPassword.text!
    do {
        try
            Locksmith.saveData(["Password" : password], forUserAccount: username)
    }catch{
        print("ERROR");
    }
}
```

Comment: Log into what? Safe from what?

Comment: Login to an App where you have some privat stuff, i don't know yet. And i thought of something where you get an email and you have to confirm your email Adress after that your registration is done.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should not use any of the those frameworks, instead download this "Keychain" framework on Github. It uses encrytion technology to store persistent data to be saved in the Keychain filesystem.

Click this Link to download the class.

[Keychain Class by Kishikawa Katsumi](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the iOS Keychain for this. From [Apple's iOS Security Guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf):

> Many apps need to handle passwords and other short but sensitive bits of data, such
>   as keys and login tokens. The iOS keychain provides a secure way to store these items

For more information on the Keychain, see [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html). If you're looking for a convenient Swift wrapper around this functionality, I would recommend [Locksmith](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith).

Comment: well actually how do i see if the right password for the specific user is given?